# "does not take parameters" when chaining method calls without periods

Tags: scala

I have a class:

```
class Greeter {
    def hi = { print ("hi"); this }
    def hello = { print ("hello"); this }
    def and = this
}
```

I would like to call the `new Greeter().hi.and.hello` as `new Greeter() hi and hello`

but this results in:

```
error: Greeter does not take parameters
              g hi and hello   
                ^
(note: the caret is under "hi")
```

I believe this means that Scala is takes the `hi` as `this` and tries to pass the `and`. But `and` is not an object. What can I pass to `apply` to chain the call to the `and` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't chain parameterless method calls like that. The general syntax that works without dots and parentheses is (informally):

`object method parameter method parameter method parameter ...`

When you write `new Greeter() hi and hello`, `and` is interpreted as a parameter to the method `hi`.

Using postfix syntax you *could* do:

```
((new Greeter hi) and) hello
```

But that's not really recommended except for specialized DSLs where you absolutely want that syntax.

Here's something you could play around with to get sort of what you want:

```
object and

class Greeter {
  def hi(a: and.type) = { print("hi"); this }
  def hello = { print("hello"); this }
}

new Greeter hi and hello
```

Comment: Thanks. But this makes the "and" mandatory. Is there a way to make it optional, without defining the method twice?

This works:

    `def hi(a: and.type) = { print("hi"); this }`
    `def hi = { print("hi"); this }`


But if I make it:

    `def hi(a: and.type = and) = { print("hi"); this }`

then:

`new Greeter hi and` is allowed, but just `new Greeter hi` is not - parentheses are now required, like `new Greeter hi()`.

Comment: `def hi: this.type = hi(and); def hi(a: and.type): this.type = { ... }` Ah, without defining the method twice...no, most probably not.